# JSON serialize return type rather than the property of the return type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON

> {"KeyValuePairs":{"Gender":"Male","IsDeveloper":true,"Language":"English"},"PreferredLanguage":"C#","PreferredIDE":"Visual Studio","PreferredSourceControl":"Team Foundation Server (TFS)"}

and it is based on the class of:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }

    public string PreferredLanguage { get; set; }

    public string PreferredIDE { get; set; }

    public string PreferredSourceControl { get; set; }

    public DataModel()
    {
        KeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

I would like to make it like the following when I serialize the class object of `DataModel`:

> {"Gender":"Male","IsDeveloper":true,"Language":"English","PreferredLanguage":"C#","PreferredIDE":"Visual Studio","PreferredSourceControl":"Team Foundation Server (TFS)"}

The reason on why I put "Gender", "IsDeveloper", or so on inside the KeyValuePairs, as because it is being generated dynamically from JSON file (it could contains anything other than "Gender", "IsDeveloper"), while the other properties like "PreferredLanguage", "PreferredIDE" and "PreferredSourceControl" does not

Also, if the above being achieved, how can I put back into KeyValuePairs for the "Gender", "IsDeveloper" or any other properties inside KeyValuePairs previously when doing the deserialization?

Basically I would like to convert all properties inside the `DataModel` class to the `Dictionary<string, object>` pairs, which `Newtonsoft.Json` did it perfectly when there is only primitive type for the return type of the property, but for my case, I would like to set the `KeyValuePairs` into `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `KeyValuePairs: Dictionary<string, object>`, and also when doing the deserialization, system will detect if there is no name of the property inside `DataModel` class, it will go add directly into `KeyValuePairs` (for example, "Gender" not exists in `DataModel` class, then it will be added into `KeyValuePairs` when doing the deserialization)

Or is there any way that I can achieve the same?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: I think you'd need a custom converter for this. Are you using System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft?

Comment: Hi @AndrewCorrigan, after I go into the link above, it seems that it will serialize any properties into dictionary<string, object> just fine even though there is nested dictionary<string, object> inside the class, but I am not really sure on how to achieve the deserialization back into KeyValuePairs.

Comment: Hi @DavidG, I am referring to the Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: You could just change your model class so it gets the values from the dictionary. Something like `public string PreferredSourceControl => KeyValuePairs["PreferredSourceControl"];` but maybe with some error checking.

Comment: @Reinhardt try using the Newtonsoft to parse it down so that `KeyValuePairs` is itself a JSON string - then implement the stuff from the question I linked as a second step. I'm not too sure how you'd do it in one hit for that particular JSON string.

Comment: @Reinhardt I still don't understand what is the problem. Do you have a DataModel but you have to serialize to different json, or you have json is different from your data model? Or both? Can you just  use a dictionary instead of DataMOdel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JsonExtensionData - Instructs the JsonSerializer to deserialize properties with no matching class member into the specified collection and write values during serialization.

```
var json="{\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"IsDeveloper\":true,\"Language\":\"English\",\"PreferredLanguage\":\"C#\",\"PreferredIDE\":\"Visual Studio\",\"PreferredSourceControl\":\"Team Foundation Server (TFS)\"}";
    
DataModel dataModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(json);
```

Test

```
    json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataModel);
```

creates the same json

class

```
public class DataModel
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }

    public string PreferredLanguage { get; set; }

    public string PreferredIDE { get; set; }

    public string PreferredSourceControl { get; set; }

    public DataModel()
    {
        KeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

if you want at first convert your json to normalized one you can do it this way:

```
var json = "{\"KeyValuePairs\":{\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"IsDeveloper\":true,\"Language\":\"English\"},\"PreferredLanguage\":\"C#\",\"PreferredIDE\":\"Visual Studio\",\"PreferredSourceControl\":\"Team Foundation Server (TFS)\"}";
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json); 

foreach (var item in ((JObject)jsonParsed["KeyValuePairs"]).Properties())
        jsonParsed.Add(item.Name, item.Value);

jsonParsed.Property("KeyValuePairs").Remove();

json = jsonParsed.ToString();
```

or you can deserialize jsonParsed as well instead of creating a new json

```
DataModel dataModel =jsonParsed.ToObject<DataModel>();
```

Comment: Hi @Serge, thank you for your answer, however the JSON that I have is like the following `{"KeyValuePairs":{"Gender":"Male","IsDeveloper":true,"Language":"English"},"PreferredLanguage":"C#","PreferredIDE":"Visual Studio","PreferredSourceControl":"Team Foundation Server (TFS)"}` and would like to serialize it to be like your JSON example, and when doing the deserialization, system will detect if there is no matching property, then will add into `KeyValuePairs` property instead.